# Laravel 5.6 api not returning while calling from ajax in post method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.6

I made a post method to supply json data as api endpoint

My route is

`Route::post('checkFuzzy', 'SolrController@checkFuzzy')->middleware('cors');`

I made *cors* validate my origin but the ajax post method is not giving anything
the ajax is as follows.

```
$('.searchme').on('click',function(){
    var company = $("input[name=Company]").val();
    console.log(company)
    $.ajax({            
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        },
        crossOrigin: true,
        type: "post",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8006/api/checkFuzzy',
        data: { 
            Company: function(){
                return company
            },
        },
        //data:'Company='+ company+'&Individual='+ individual,
        success: function(msg){
        alert('wow' + msg);
     }
    });
});
```

and the response in request headers is as follows

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/html
Origin: http://localhost:8006
Referer: http://localhost:8006/searchSolr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: e522xOu6IhXGCXLDyw929zCogVcXcaZ5yYWwXDo4
```

the Cors.php is as follows

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application, x-xsrf-token, x-csrf-token');
        return $response;
    }
```

The status code is 200.

Comment: You should include error from console/log and status you get (is it 200, 404, 422)?.

Comment: Status code is 200

Comment: And where is your controller code? Do you return anything from controller?

Comment: Yes an array, it works fine with same domain and also with postman

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the return type. The return type should be a json not an array.

```
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'result' => $calCulatedValue
        ]);
```